# UserInfo information class with a database

Tags: c#

I am no expert in C#, the opposite really, I just wanted an overall review on my `UserInfo` class that gets user information from a database using MySQL. I was also wondering if it is a good idea to really process the data in the way I did, getting everything from the database, even the things that aren't needed. But I think this way is a lot more tidy and neat. I was just wondering what you would say about it.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Scratch.Application.Habbo.Users
{
    class UserInfo
    {
        private Dictionary<string, string> _userInfo;

        public UserInfo(int Id)
        {
            this._userInfo = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            using (var DbCon = Scratch.GetEnvironment().GetDatabase().GenerateNewConnection())
            {
                DbCon.AssignQuery("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = @id");
                DbCon.RegisterParameter("id", Id);
                DbCon.OpenConnection();

                using (MySqlDataReader Reader = DbCon.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (Reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (Reader.Read())
                        {
                            for (int index = 0; index < Reader.FieldCount; index++)
                            {
                                //bypass duplicate error, just replaces if duplicate
                                this._userInfo[Reader.GetName(index)] = Reader.GetString(index);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void UpdateData(string Key, string NewValue)
        {
            if (this._userInfo.ContainsKey(Key))
                this._userInfo.Add(Key, "");

            this._userInfo[Key] = NewValue;
        }

        public string GetString(string Key)
        {
            return this._userInfo[Key];
        }

        public int GetInt(string Key)
        {
            return int.Parse(this._userInfo[Key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you do this:

```
if (this._userInfo.ContainsKey(Key))
    this._userInfo.Add(Key, "");

this._userInfo[Key] = NewValue;
```

Those first two lines are completely superfluous; moreover if you need to get a value from a `Dictionary<T, T>` and aren't sure the key is present, you need to use [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.TryGetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx).

---

Local variables like `Reader` need to be camelCase. Ditto parameters like `Key` and `NewValue`.

---

Why aren't you using an ORM like [Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider) instead of this ugly, needlessly generic code? I mean: `public string GetString(string Key)`, `public int GetInt(string Key)` -- really?